# Is it possible to have multiple layouts on a drag-able list?

Tags: android

I have multiple classes with different layouts which I call them Widgets in my app (this is a whole different thing from so called "Android Widgets"). I want to put instances of these classes beside each other in an activity called Dashboard. So users can change the place and settings of these widgets inside the dashboard. Any suggestions?

I tried to use itemtouchhelper but the problem is drag and drop is only surpport one type layout with one recyclerview AFAIK.it is strange drag and drop over multiple viewtype.

like so:

```java
 private void swapOneAndTwoSizeWidget(int from, int to) {
        List<WidgetInfo> list = mAdapter.getList();
        WidgetInfo source = list.get(from);
        WidgetInfo target = list.get(to);
        // swap two column item and one column item
        swapLocation(source, target); 
        swapLocation(target, list.get(to + 1));
        updateSort(source, target, list.get(to + 1)); 
        moveItems(from, to); 
    }

    private void swapLocation(WidgetInfo a, WidgetInfo b) {
        int tempX = a.getLocationX();
        int tempY = a.getLocationY();
        a.setLocationX(b.getLocationX());
        a.setLocationY(b.getLocationY());
        b.setLocationX(tempX);
        b.setLocationY(tempY);
    }

    private void updateSort(WidgetInfo... widgets) {
        List<WidgetInfo> listToSwap = new ArrayList<>();
        for (WidgetInfo widget : widgets) {
            if (!widget.isAdd()) {
                listToSwap.add(widget);
            }
        }
        mAdapter.updateSort(listToSwap);
    }

    private void moveItems(int from, int to) {
        List<WidgetInfo> list = mAdapter.getList();
        if (from < to) {
            for (int i = from; i < to + 1; i++) {
                Collections.swap(list, i, i + 1);
            }
            mAdapter.notifyItemMoved(from, to + 1);
        } else {
            for (int i = from; i > to; i--) {
                Collections.swap(list, i, i - 1);
            }
            mAdapter.notifyItemMoved(from, to);
        }
    }
```

swap before:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gV9vn.png)

swap after:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0hto.png)

my expect is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJvNm.png)

Comment: "I tried to use drag and drop api or itemtouchhelper but the problem is each list mush have one layout AFAIK" - that is untrue. A list (I assume you mean RecyclerView) can have any number of different layouts that comprise the list of views. Beyond that, your question is a bit vague and needs more details.

Comment: hi @dominicoder i have add some  details and code now